# F# Matching results of recursive calls using higher order functions

Tags: f#

Given a simple function, where we do pattern matching on the result of a recursive call, such as:

```
let rec sumProd = function
    | []      -> (0,1)
    | x::rest -> let (rSum,rProd) = sumProd rest
                 (x + rSum,x * rProd)

sumProd [2;5] //Expected (7, 10)
```

How would I go about changing it into something using higher order functions, e.g. `foldBack`?

```
let sumProdHigherOrder lst = 
    List.foldBack (fun x acc -> (acc + x, acc * x)) lst (0,0)
```

The above seemed almost like the way to do it, but calling it gives the error: `The type 'int' does not match the type 'int * int'`

```
sumProdHigherOrder [2;5] //Expected (7, 10)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your missing the tuple functions `fst` and `snd`:

```
List.foldBack (fun x acc -> (fst acc + x, snd acc * x)) [2;5] (0,1)
// val it : int * int = (7, 10)
```

Or even better, decomposing the tuple at the lambda. I see you just found it:

```
List.foldBack (fun x (s, m) -> (s + x, m * x)) [2;5] (0,1)
```

Also note that since the operations are commutative you can do a straight `fold`:

```
List.fold (fun (s, m) x -> (s + x, m * x)) (0,1) [2;5]
```

It will be more efficient.

Comment: That makes sense. Is my own answer a silly way of doing it?

Comment: No, your answer is the basically the same as this. You're decomposing the tuple in the lambda. I would actually wrote it like you did, instead of ``fst`` and ``snd``.

Comment: Alright. However, I'm a little confused about the mechanism of `fst` and `snd` in your example. Are those just for telling it to use different functions on each element in the tuple? I can then see how decomposing the tuple in the lambda would be better, unless you know you're only working on pairs?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It reads better and of course if you have a tuple of more than two elements there is not other way.

Comment: Technically there would be another way, but you'd have to define your own functions. E.g., for a 3-tuple you could define `let firstOf3 (x, _, _) = x; let secondOf3 (_, y, _) = y; let thirdOf3 (_, _, z) = z` and then use those functions the way you use `fst` and `snd` for 2-tuples. In a few cases, this can lead to easier-to-read code. But most of the time, doing that is just silly and you should just deconstruct the tuple at the point where you're going to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Right! Of course it shouldn't be the same accumulator that gets passed through the list. After staring intensely at the code for some minutes, I figured it out:

```
let sumProdHigherOrder lst = 
    List.foldBack (fun x (acc,acc') -> (acc + x, acc' * x)) lst (0,1)
```